# Commutant of group of order $p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Prove, that commutant of a group of order $p^3$ has order at most $p$.

The order can be $1, p, p^2, p^3$. $1$ and $p$ are OK.

Commutant with order of $p^3$ is equal to the group, so the center of group is trivial, which can't be true.

But how to show there is no commutant of order $p^2$?

Comment: A group of order $p^2$ is abelian, and every group of order $p^3$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$. So the commutator subgroup cannot have order greater than $p$. in particular, no commutator can have order greater than $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each group with $p^2$ elements is abelian.

Take a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|H|=p$ then $|G/H|=p^2$,

Since $G/H$ is abelian then $aHbH=bHaH$ for all $a,b\in G$, this implies $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in H$ then
$[G,G]<H$, so  $[G,G]=\{e\}$ because $H$ is also abelian too.

Comment: Not every subgroup of order $p$ needs to be normal. You need to pick $H$ normal.

Comment: Ok, Arturo you are correct... It is needed to proved the second part of your first sentence in the comment below the OP.